# Analytical mechanics, constant angle between velocity and acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity

> A particle moves in a plane so that the angle between velocity and acceleration is constant $\alpha$. Angle $\phi$ between velocity and fixed coordinate axis varies according to a given law: $\phi(t)$. Find velocity and acceleration as $\phi$ functions, if at the starting moment t=0 we know $V(0)=V_0, \phi(0)=\phi_0$.[image]

I tried to solve it in polar coordinates: $V=(dr/dt, r*d\phi/dt); a=(d^2r/dt^2-r*(d\phi/dt)^2, r*d^2\phi/dt^2+2*dr/dt*d\phi/dt)$.

Now these vectors' second coordinate is the angle between them and fixed axis; is it true that i could subtract one from the second and equate it to $\alpha$?

So that $r*d^2\phi/dt^2+2*dr/dt*d\phi/dt-r*d\phi/dt = \alpha$, where $\phi(t)$ and it's derivatives is known? However, i don't know what's to do after.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions. Can you try making a question about some concepts that you'd need to solve this problem?

Comment: @SilverLight: Was it specified which is the fixed coordinate axis?

Comment: @WinterSoldier: A picture was added, is it clear now?

Comment: Try writing $\mathbf{\vec{v}}(t) \, = \,  v_0 \, f(t) \, \left( \cos \phi(t) \, \hat{\mathbf{i}} \, + \, \sin \phi(t) \, \hat{\mathbf{j}} \right) $ and use $\mathbf{\vec{v}}(t) \cdot \frac{d \mathbf{\vec{v}}(t)}{d t} = |\mathbf{\vec{v}}(t)| |\frac{d \mathbf{\vec{v}}(t)}{d t}| \cos \alpha $, with the initial conditions $f(0)= 1$ and $\phi(0
) = \phi_0$.

Comment: @ secavara
I got this solution for $v(t)=$ 

${\it v0}\,{{\rm e}^{ \left( {\frac {d}{dt}}\varphi  \left( t \right) 
 \right) \cot \left( \alpha \right) t}}
$ but i am not sure about it. Du you have any solution for this problem?
Thank you

Comment: @Eli Oh sorry, I didn't get a notification for your comment and just saw it. There are basically two types of solutions. One type are those with trajectories that are straight lines ($\phi(t) = \phi_0$) with either always increasing ($\alpha = 0$) or always decreasing ($\alpha = \pi$) magnitude of the velocity. This solution can be written as $\mathbf{\vec{v}} = v_0 \exp \left[ g(t) \right] \left(\cos \phi_0 \mathbf{\hat{i}} + \sin \phi_0 \mathbf{\hat{j}} \right)$, where $g(0) = 0$, $\frac{dg}{dt} \neq 0$ and $ \mathrm{sign}\left(\frac{dg}{dt}\right) = \cos \alpha$.

Comment: There is a second type of solutions, which have $0 < \alpha < \pi$, including the case of circular motion ($\alpha = \pi/2$). In this case the solution is of the form $\mathbf{\vec{v}} = v_0 \exp \left[ \mathrm{sign}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right) \cot \alpha \left(\phi(t) - \phi_0 \right)\right] \left(\cos \phi(t) \mathbf{\hat{i}} + \sin \phi(t) \mathbf{\hat{j}} \right)$.